# update one table from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two 2 tables in MySQL

The first one contains ID,name,address,phone
the second one Name and email

I want to update all email from table 2 to table 1 for same name

It's a very large database so i need to do it auto(more than 20k records)

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far? 2. What does two 2 tables means?

Answer (score 1):

The format for such updates in MySQL typically uses a `join`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.name = t2.name
    set t1.email = t2.email;
```

I would caution you that matching on names can introduce complications -- with misspellings, middle initials, accented characters, and the like causing mismatches.